# MS office files downloaded from gmail are not opened

Tags: microsoft-office

when i download any office file (doc, ppt, xls) from g-mail or any other website they dont open and error msg is displayed that the file is corrupted. i have re-installed MS Office but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Error when opening MS office files downloaded from gmail

> They don't open and an error message  is displayed that the file is corrupted.

You need to disable "Protected View" for downloaded files. See below for instructions on how do this.

---

#### Can't open excel and powerpoint files downloaded from Internet

> I have problem opening excel and powerpoint files downloaded from the Internet using my Office 2010.  Error messages - "file corrupted" (but it can't be that all files are corrupted)?

...

> If you are using Office 2010, you need to check your settings in the
>   Trust Center.
>
> - Go to File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Protected View.
> - Make sure the first box is NOT checked.
>
> [image]

Source [Can't open excel and powerpoint files downloaded from Internet](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-office_install/cant-open-excel-and-powerpoint-files-downloaded/7db4f743-9d31-4c54-bb14-003e47978872)

Note:

- You may also have to uncheck the other two boxes in the "Protected View" section.

---

#### Further reading

- [What is Protected View?](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/What-is-Protected-View-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653)

Comment: i tried it multiple times :P but i don't have that much reputations, new to the stack :)